# Multiple Oracle datasources on JBoss are used incorrectly

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jboss

I have JBoss 4 with 2 Oracle datasources: CurrentDS and ArchiveDS.

But hibernate uses only scheme for CurrentDS when creates tables from annotations, and scheme for ArchiveDS stays empty. My opinion - when he starts creating tables for Archive he finds just created tables in CurrentDS and thinks that they already exist (using wrong credentials).

This works OK on Postgres, what could it be about on Oracle?

```
<datasources>

<local-tx-datasource>
   <jndi-name>CurrentDS</jndi-name>
   <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</connection-url>
   <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
   <user-name>current</user-name>
   <password>password</password>          

   <metadata>
     <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>    
   </metadata>

 </local-tx-datasource>

 <local-tx-datasource>
   <jndi-name>ArchiveDS</jndi-name>
   <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</connection-url>
   <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
   <user-name>archive</user-name>
   <password>password</password>          

   <metadata>
     <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>    
   </metadata>

 </local-tx-datasource>

</datasources>
```

Comment: Try using this format instead: `jdbc:oracle:thin:[user/password]@[host][:port]:SID` and remove `<user-name/>` and `<password />` tags. Perhaps Hibernate needs connection-strings to differ?

Comment: No, changing string doesn't help. The solution is to specify hibernate.default_schema for each oracle datasource